# taglib call to managedbean call

Tags: jsf, facelets, taglib, bcel

i have an managed bean(session scope) like this:

```
class Home {// as homeBean
  public void doSomething(ActionEvent ae, int a, int b){
    System.out.println("result="+(a+b));
  }
}
```

i like to call this

```
<a4j:commandLink actionListener="#{homeBean:doSomething(1,2)}"/>
```

what i know is: it isnt possible to use a and b parameter.

ok: this should be in example a "static" possibility to invoke this using an taglib:

```
public class CoolTaglib implements TagLibrary{
   ...
  public static void doSomething(int a, int b) {
    getHomeBeanFromSession().doSomething(a,b);
  }
}
```

what about to invoke it dynamicly? using bcel or URLClassLoader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This EL expression syntax is for static methods only and must be defined in a tag library and have the namespace defined in the view:

```
 #{namespacePrefix:fn(arg)}
```

This EL expression with invokes a [parameterized method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html#gjhbz) on an object instance:

```
#{someInstance.method(arg)}
```

The second form is available in [Expression Language 2.2](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html) or above (Java EE 6.) Similar expressions are supported in some 3rd party JSF libraries prior to this.

It is possible to look up a managed bean from a static method so long as it is executed within a JSF context:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
SomeBean someBean = context.getApplication()
                           .evaluateExpressionGet(context, 
                                                  "#{someBean}", SomeBean.class);
```

This is not the ideal approach however. This code was written against JSF 2; prior versions use different dynamic lookup calls.

If you need a bean in a static method, use an expression of the form:

```
#{namespacePrefix:fn(someBean, 1, 2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh cool, i found a way to work:

```
public class ... implements TagLibrary {

@Override
public Method createFunction(String taglib, String functionName) {
    if (!map.containsKey(functionName)) {

        String classname = "de.Test" + functionName;
        ClassGen _cg = new ClassGen(classname,
                "java.lang.Object", "Test.java", ACC_PUBLIC | ACC_SUPER,
                new String[] {});
        ConstantPoolGen _cp = _cg.getConstantPool();
        InstructionFactory _factory = new InstructionFactory(_cg, _cp);

        Method meth = find(functionName, getNavigation());
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = meth.getParameterTypes();
        int countParams = parameterTypes.length;
        Type[] types = new Type[countParams];
        String[] names = new String[countParams];
        for (int i = 0; i < countParams; i++) {
            types[i] = new ObjectType(parameterTypes[i].getName());
            names[i] = "arg" + i;
        }

        InstructionList il = new InstructionList();

        MethodGen staticMethod = new MethodGen(ACC_PUBLIC | ACC_STATIC,
                Type.OBJECT, types, names, functionName, getClass()
                        .getName(), il, _cp);

        InstructionHandle ih_1 = il.append(new PUSH(_cp, functionName));
        il.append(new PUSH(_cp, countParams));

        il.append(_factory.createNewArray(Type.OBJECT, (short) 1));
        il.append(InstructionConstants.DUP);

        for (int i = 0; i < countParams; i++) {
            il.append(new PUSH(_cp, i));

            il.append(_factory.createLoad(Type.OBJECT, i));
            il.append(InstructionConstants.AASTORE);
            if (i != countParams - 1)
                il.append(InstructionConstants.DUP);
        }

        il.append(_factory.createInvoke(getClass().getName(),
                "call", Type.OBJECT, new Type[] { Type.STRING,
                        new ArrayType(Type.OBJECT, 1) },
                Constants.INVOKESTATIC));
        InstructionHandle ih_25 = il.append(_factory
                .createReturn(Type.OBJECT));
        staticMethod.setMaxStack();
        staticMethod.setMaxLocals();
        _cg.addMethod(staticMethod.getMethod());
        il.dispose();

        try {

            byte[] bytes = _cg.getJavaClass().getBytes();

            InjectingClassLoader icl = new InjectingClassLoader();

            Method find = 
                    find(functionName, icl.load(classname, bytes));

            map.put(functionName, find);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Method method = map.get(functionName);
    return method;

}

public static Object call(String functionname, Object[] arguments) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Navigation myTargetBean = getNavigation();
    Method proxyMethod = find(functionname,myTargetBean);

    Object result = proxyMethod.invoke(myTargetBean, arguments);

    return result;
}
```

Now, i am able to call #{cms:doSomething(1,2)}

Comment: Do you have an "simple" way for jsf 1.2? "simple" means to me to not have all those getter-setter-overhead.

Comment: If you happen to run Servlet 2.5, you could install JBoss EL to have EL 2.2 like enhancements.